# Взаимодействие сервлета с компонентой enterprise java beans

Tags: java-ee, ejb

Каким образом получить ссылку на объект локального интерфейса java beans в сервлете.

Локальный интерфейс:

```
package model;

import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface GenericBeanLocal {

    public String info();
}
```

Класс Java beans:

package 
    model;

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless(mappedName = "genbean")
public class GenericBean implements GenericBeanRemote, GenericBeanLocal {

    public GenericBean() {}
    public String info() {
        return ""+new Date();
    }

}
```

Сервлет в котором необходимо получить ссылку на локальный интерфейс компоненты java beans:

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import model.GenericBeanLocal;

public class CheckAvtorization extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    private GenericBeanLocal ejblocalinter;
    public CheckAvtorization() {
        System.out.println("CheckAvtorization Constructor()");
                            }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
            System.out.println("CheckAvtorization doPost()");

    String pass = req.getParameter("pas");
    String log = req.getParameter("log");

    Connection conn = my.service.db.MySqlConnector.getConnection(log,pass);
    if(conn!=null){
        out.println("Авторизация выполнена "+log);
    }else{
        out.println("Пшол Вон"+log+"/"+pass);
    }
    out.println("<hr> EJB JenericBeanLocal Interface : "+ejblocalinter);

    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

}
```

Tomcat выдает ошибку связанную с невозможностью получить объект интерфейса GenericBeanLocal.
Код ошибки:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class servlets.CheckAvtorization

type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class servlets.CheckAvtorization

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class servlets.CheckAvtorization
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [servlets.CheckAvtorization/ejblocalinter] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [servlets.CheckAvtorization].
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
```

Answer (score 1):

А Вы уверены что "`Tomcat` выдает ошибку связанную с невозможностью получить объект интерфейса `GenericBeanLocal`."? ;)
Я бы попробовал изменить модификатор доступа метода сервлета.
Параметры "`log`" и "`pas`" конечно-же заявлены в `Context сервлета`? Кстати а какой объект у Вас соответствует ссылочной переменной "`ejblocalinter`" и какую функцию у Вас выполняет блок `try{}catch{}`?

Comment: Добавил к методу сервлета doPost модификатор доступа public - ошибка та же.